# Will I lost my Keychain with a new certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keychain, provisioning-profile

I have an application already in the store that use Keychain to store passwords.
I want to publish an update of the application, the problem is that I don't have the original certificate anymore (it was expired and I created another).
Reading Apple's documentation it says:

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile
>   used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

If I edit my provisioning profile with a different certificate, will my users lose their passwords when I will upgrade the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can upload the app into the store (so update the old one), the users will not recognize anything of this ;)

What's saved in their keychain will be bound to the Bundle an stays at least until the application is deleted.

You can revoke and re-create your cert, and assign it to your provisioning profile without any further consequences.